# Resume playlist playback

Tags: windows, audio, podcasts, playlists

I'm trying to make my machine wake me up in the morning by resuming playback of my playlist of podcasts.

What I've tried:

- Getting a mediaplayer that resumes **playlist** playback when you start it: There is none!
- Getting a mediaplayer that supports sending PLAY command from command line: There is none!

Currently I'm making an ahk script to focus my VLC window and send spacebar (resume). Any better solutions to resume playlist playback?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I went ahead and solved this with autohotkey. I used this script:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx

IfWinExist, ^.*VLC media player$
{
    WinActivate
    Send {Space}
    return
}
```

Save it as an .ahk file, compile it with autohotkey (rightclick->compile) and you'll have a .exe

Open task scheduler, make a new task, check "wake computer to run" and choose the .exe you just made as the program to run. Pick time and frequency to run and you're done.

Obviously with this solution you have to leave VLC running at all times, sadly.